# What should I do if I've asked a question about something that isn't possible?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I recently asked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316299/how-to-run-php-function-directly-after-a-specific-magento-2-cli-command) but it appears that the answer is simply 'you can't do this but there are other ways to achieve a similar effect'. I've placed a bounty on my question too, to draw significance. Of the two good answers that I have received, how do i choose when they both ultimately say the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either accept one of the answers which you may be like or you do not accept any answers. It is total you chose. The forum does not have any strict rule to the accept answer of a question.

If I am at your place then I will accept the first answer when both answers are given the same ideas. But it is my ideology to tackle such a scenario.

End it is your call accept and chose the answer or Not accept anyone.